# how to retrieve a url from a link on a website using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, url, jsoup, yelp

Alright so I finished my Yelp scanner, and everything is running great. What I want to do now is have the program retrieve the url for each link to each business, go to that page, and scan for whether it contains:

```html
xlink:href="#30x30_bullhorn"></use>
```

I pretty much have a good idea of how I'm going to go about doing that, however, I can't seem to find a jSoup method that would retrieve a link's url. Is there somewhere in the page's HTML that would have the url? I'm not very proficient with HTML at all, so 90% of what I'm looking at is gibbering. Here's an example link if you want to check out what I'm referring to.

https://www.yelp.com/search?find_loc=nj&start=10 is the main page, that I need to obtain the url for the page https://www.yelp.com/biz/la-cocina-newark. The orange bullhorn is what I am trying to get it to retrieve. Here's my code btw:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YelpScrapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception
    {        
        //Variables
        String description;
        String location;
        int pages;
        int parseCount = 0;
        Document document;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Perform a Search
        System.out.print("Enter a description: ");
        description = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a state: ");
        location = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How many pages should we scan? ");
        pages = keyboard.nextInt();

        String descString = "find_desc=" + description.replace(' ', '+') + "&";
        String locString = "find_loc=" + location.replace(' ', '+') + "&";
        int number = 0;

        String url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?" + descString + locString + "start=" + number;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Fetch Data From Yelp
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= pages ; i++)
        {

            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements nameElements = document.select(".indexed-biz-name span");
            Elements addressElements = document.select(".secondary-attributes address");
            Elements phoneElements = document.select(".biz-phone");

            for (Element element : nameElements)
            {
                names.add(element.text());
            }

            for (Element element : addressElements)
            {
                address.add(element.text());
            }

            for (Element element : phoneElements)
            {
                phone.add(element.text());
            }

            for (int index = 0 ; index < 10 ; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("\nLead " + parseCount);
                System.out.println("Company Name: " + names.get(parseCount));
                System.out.println("Address: " + address.get(parseCount));
                System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phone.get(parseCount));

                parseCount = parseCount + 1;
            }

            number = number + 10;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use the Inspect element of Chrome Developer tools, as it makes it incredibly easy to locate elements in the DOM (you said you aren't comfortable with HTML, well you certainly will be after this and using Inspect is a great learning tool). Focusing the inspector on the "View Now" button, you'll get to this:

`<a href="https://www.yelp.com/biz_redir?cachebuster=1479918865&amp;s=1c73b4bdc9110f6e6dc72fff48cd6379d6eaac0cd6d15794a9414e546ad5a927&amp;src_bizid=U2eO8yFSc9YTf_SPnog8cw&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lacocinanewark.com%2F%23%21menu%2Fcl69&amp;website_link_type=cta" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="ybtn ybtn--primary ybtn--small ybtn-cta" data-component-bound="true">View Now</a>`.

You'll have to figure out how to traverse down to this, and `childNodes()` will be helpful in traversing down. Then you can use `getElementsByClass("ybtn ybtn--primary ybtn--small ybtn-cta")` to get to that specific class where the link is, and then use the `.attr()` method of the `Element` class to get the href: `.attr("href");`.

Comment: The inspector tool has been tons of help! It's nice that it highlights exactly where it is on the page, so I know exactly where to look.

Comment: @BrandonWoodruff exactly. Modern web pages are so complex that it would be terrifying to build any sort of scraper without something like the inspector.